# An example of infimal convolution for nonconvex functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed vectorial space. Given two functions $\phi,\psi:E\to(−\infty, +\infty]$, the inf-convolution of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is defined as follows: for every $x\in E$, let
$$
(\phi\nabla\psi)(x)=\inf_{x\in E}\{\phi(x-y)+\psi(y)\}.
$$
In the particular case where $\psi(x)=\alpha\|x\|^2$, $\alpha>0$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray}
(\alpha\|\cdot\|^2\nabla\psi)(x)=\inf_{x\in E}\{\alpha\|x-y\|^2+\psi(y)\}.
\end{eqnarray}
It is a well-known result that if $\psi$ is convex, then $\alpha\|\cdot\|^2\nabla\psi$ is convex. I am looking for an example where that infimal convolution $\alpha\|\cdot\|^2\nabla\psi$ still convex but the function $f$ it is not convex. I have made some research, but I found results only when both functions are convex and I wasn't able to provide an example. So, there is an example when $\alpha\|\cdot\|^2\nabla\psi$ still convex even when $f$ is not?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example is $\psi(x) = -\alpha \, \|x\|^2$.

Comment: Yes, but the trivial example I am not interested in.

Comment: You can also take $-\gamma \,\|x\|^2$ for $0 < \gamma < \alpha$.